# Network Setup for an NVidia DGX-1?

Tags: networking, drivers, nvidia, system-installation, internet

We are trying to setup the network for an NVidia DGX 1 workstation.

We've connected a network cable that we know works (Tested it on another ubuntu laptop with no WIFI connected).

When we connect it to the DGX1 we don't get an IP address and Firefox just shows the page "Hmm We're having problems finding that site".

Any ideas on how to get the network working?

[We've tried this](https://superuser.com/questions/181076/how-do-i-check-if-my-network-card-has-been-detected-and-is-working#) and we don't see `eth0` at all

Comment: Please run this one line `sudo printf '\n*** ADAPTER INFO ***\n\n' && sudo inxi -N -v 7 | grep -E 'Network|Ethernet' && lspci | grep -E 'Network|Ethernet' && printf '\n*** ADAPTER DETAILS ***\n\n' && sudo lshw -class network && printf '\n*** IP INFO ***\n\n' &&ip addr show` in the terminal and add the output to your question. Thank you

Comment: Hi @Raffa - Thanks we ended up running the system setup that was one of the options the machine comes with and it fixed it.

Comment: This is good news. Please consider adding an answer below with steps and as much explanation as possible to help others with the same issue. You will be automatically allowed to accept your answer to your question after two days, so please do so as well. Thank you

Comment: Well - The first part (Running setup at boot) was easy.  At least it got DHCP working.  Turns out the machine did not ship with the NVidia Systems Administration Manager (nvsm) either so now we are asking them how to get that to resolve the rest of the networking issues ... It's a slow process.